# Can anyone Identify the make, model and year of this car?

Tags: ford, thunderbird

Photo is from the 1980's
[image: Found this photo and am now wondering what the make, model and year for this car. THe photo is from the 1980's I am guessing the car is from the 1960's]

Found this photo and am now wondering what the make, model and year for this car. THe photo is from the 1980's I am guessing the car is from the 1960's

Comment: I came here hope to see a ford merkur from the title, still, thanks for posting

Comment: Google lens says it is a Ford Thunderbird. I found [this image](https://worldwideauctioneers.com/wp-content/uploads/AA209020-600x400.jpg) too.

Answer (score 29):

I believe that is a 1960 Ford Thunderbird:

[image: 1960 Ford Thunderbird]

The 1959 had only two lights on each side and the 1961 was significantly restyled and had only a single light on each side.

1959 Thunderbird:

[image: 1959 Thunderbird]

1961 Thunderbird:

[image: 1961 Thunderbird]

Very distinctive vehicle and the key here is the Thunderbird logo in the center of the trunk lid.

Article on this model here:

[1960 Ford Thunderbird - Hemmings](https://www.hemmings.com/stories/article/strikingly-stylish-1960-ford-thunderbird)

Comment: Thank you jwh20. I should have recognized the Thunderbird logo having lived near the Thunderbird assembly plant many years ago

Comment: It sure looks like a T-Bird, but the trunk lid on it is funky compared to the image you posted. There's the ridge above the symbol and the chrome piece center/top. Still, I don't see it being anything *other* than a '60 T-Bird. EDIT: Ah, it's just a trick of light and that the image is poor quality.

Comment: The appendage just behind the rear window is for a radio aerial. Not all models have this, but if you go [here](https://collectingcars.com/for-sale/1960-ford-thunderbird) (before the car is sold!), you will find several pictures (for example, [this](https://collectingcars.imgix.net/005262/Ford-Thunderbird-2832.jpg?w=1263&fit=fillmax&crop=edges&auto=format,compress&cs=srgb&q=85) shows it clearly).